# Layout in Cakephp 3?

Tags: templates, cakephp, layout

Good day everyone !
I have a Cakephp 3 project.

File `src/Template/Layout/Default.ctp` contains code (header, footer..) to import some vew like `src/Template/User/index.ctp` or `src/Template/Posts/add.ctp` automatically.

But it is Admin Panel, now I want build views for front-end, I dont want to use the same layout.How can I use different header/footer layout for `src/Template/Home/index.ctp`... ?.

Here is my folder

[image: [1]]

Tks for reading !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the set the layout in your `Controller` or define some conditions on which the frontend `View` should be loaded in **/src/View/AppView.php**.

See the [docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#layouts).

For the Controller approach:

```
// Set the layout.
$this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('admin');

// Before 3.4
$this->viewBuilder()->layout('admin');

// Before 3.1
$this->layout = 'admin';
```

Comment: I hate this... why cakephp dev do something fragile like this, deprecated for every version

Comment: If anyone else is struggling with this - I'm on Cake 3.8 and only the last option worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

```
use Cake\Event\Event;

public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('admin');
}
```

Add these codes in your controller => that will change your entire controller's action layout for rendering to 'admin'

To change one action layout, follow [Mary's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44275931/7311767) code.